# count unique values in a group, and exclude already counted rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to count all unique visitors group by day.But i want to exclude the visitor if he has already visited any previous day.My sample table is as below

```
mysql> select * from visitor;
+-------+------------+--------------+
| user  | visit_date | No Of Visits |
+-------+------------+--------------+
| user1 | 20150101   | 10           |
| user2 | 20150102   | 1            |
| user3 | 20150101   | 1            |
| user1 | 20150102   | 2            |
+-------+------------+--------------+
```

My requirement is to get a distinct count of user group by visit date but to exclude already visited user.

20150101 --> User1 and user 3 visited

20150102 --> User 2 visited (Exclude user1 as he has already visited)

```
+----------------------+------------+
| count(distinct user) | visit_date |
+----------------------+------------+
|                    2 | 20150101   |
|                    1 | 20150102   |
+----------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Apparently OP meant to say _any_ previous day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved

select count(*),hr from (select user, min(visit_date)as hr
      from visitor v
      group by user) as data group by hr

Comment: There's no way that query works once you have more than two days worth of data.

Comment: In your questions you wrote _the_ previous day instead of _any_ previous day. It makes a big difference.

Comment: Updated the question as "any previous day"".Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select visit_date, count(distinct user)
from visitors as v1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from visitors as v2
    where
            v2.user = v1.user
        and v2.visit_date = date_sub(v1.visit_date, interval 1 day)
)
group by visit_date
```

or

```
select v1.visit_date, count(distinct v1.user)
from
    visitors as v1
    left outer join visitors as v2
        on      v2.user = v1.user
            and v2.visit_date = date_sub(v1.visit_date, interval 1 day)
where v2.user is null
group by v1.visit_date
```

Not really sure if `DISTINCT` is actually necessary in the aggregate.

Comment: Both the solutions are not working.For 20150102  the count should be 1

Comment: Actually the second query shouldn't have worked at all without the edits I just made. Remove the `GROUP BY`s and change to `SELECT *` so we can see the results.